# Using update_attributes with column type of array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, updatemodel

I have a languages column which is an array of strings with

```
add_column :table, :languages, :string, array: true, default: []
```

When I use `update_attributes` on that model, all columns are being updated except the languages column which remains `[]`

Is there anything special needed to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you post an array onto an action in the controller, you should permit like this:

```
params.require(:table).permit( {:languages => []}, :other_field, :other_field2... )
```

Comment: languages is permitted in the table_params

Comment: Is it permitted as an array?

Comment: this kind of permission will only allow empty arrays

Comment: I copied/pasted this from an app of mine and it is working perfectly... It tells the controller to permit languages as an array, not an empty array

Comment: Glad to having helped.